# Need to know common ways to communicate with backend in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, request, backend

I'm new to the iOS world, but I have been working as a Software Developer and worked on many Web Applications with Laravel and PHP.

My Question is now if PHP is a good server-side language for Swift, then what is the common way to communicate with a Server in Swift.

I'm thinking to make a REST API call to a Laravel or PHP Application to get and store all Datas I need for my Project.

Thanks for your Tips

Comment: REST API call is good approach.

Comment: First of all: using a REST API is indeed a great idea, Laravel already returns JSON by default and Swift can parse this very easily back in dictonaries (for example). However the way you ask it is heavily opinion based and because of that offtopic on this site. Best of luck.

Comment: It is good one. Even has special libs as Passport for api auth: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport

Comment: I did make answer for your question, @mrfr34k. I wish you check right answer if you got any helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your way for beginners (Swift, iOS developer)

**Using cocoa framework in Swift**

*URLSession*

Initialize a URL object and a URLSessionDataTask from URLSession. Then run the task with resume().

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in
    print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))
}

task.resume()
```

*NSURLConnection*

First, initialize a URL and a URLRequest:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")
let request = URLRequest(URL: url!)
```

Then, you can load the request asynchronously with:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: 
NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
    print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}
```

**Using Alamofire - Awesome framework**

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

*Making a Request*

```
import Alamofire

Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get")
```

*Response Handling*

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
         .response { request, response, data, error in
              print(request)
              print(response)
              print(error)
          }
```